# Replacing a function 'transformPointsForward' in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I have some problem in Matlab.
I'm working and try to use this ref: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/gs/object-detection-and-tracking.html
But in the last Matlab version there's no function named like 'transformPointsForward'.
What can I replace it?
Block, where it uses:

```
boxPolygon = [1, 1;...                           % top-left
        size(boxImage, 2), 1;...                 % top-right
        size(boxImage, 2), size(boxImage, 1);... % bottom-right
        1, size(boxImage, 1);...                 % bottom-left
        1, 1];                   % top-left again to close the polygon
    newBoxPolygon = transformPointsForward(tform, boxPolygon.Location);
    figure; imshow(sceneImage);
```

Many thanks!

Comment: transformPointsFoward was added in 2013a, to the best of my knowledge. Do you have the [image processing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/image/)? That is required to use the function.

Comment: Oops! Sorry. I have Matlab 2012b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`transformPointsFoward`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/affine3d.transformpointsforward.html) is only available from 2013a onwards. If you're using an older version, you will want to look at [`tformfwd`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/tformfwd.html) instead, also from the Image Processing toolbox.

Comment: How can I use it in this case?

Comment: Well in the 2D case, they're very similar. You're calling `transformPointsFoward(tform,U)` where U is a 2-by-*n* matrix. You'd just change that to `tformfwd(tform,U)`. I think the only difference would be that your transform constructed by [`maketform`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/maketform.html) will use the 2D form. There's an example on the page.